# TFS Add Binaries Folder

Tags: tfs

I have my folders structured like this:

[image]

I would like my TFS to look like the image above. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

The second image is the inside of the source folder. How do I tell TFS to start at the root? How do I include the bin folder, which has several shared binaries, in my project?

Comment: You want to checkin the bin folder to TFS, because there are some binaries in it you need to compile? This is bad structure, because when you checkin the bin folder to TFS it will be set to Read-Only in your workspaces. So every developer gets an error when trying to compile. The best practice for third party libraries would be a new folder in parallel to SolutionFolder named commonLibs for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag and drop the bin folder from Windows Explorer to where you want it in the `Source Control Explorer` and then `Include` the binaries that are on the `Exclude` tab and check everything in then.

Answer (score 0):

Its Possible if you mapped the folder containing the Binaries to a folder under the Team Project in TFS